# Make a private implementation from an interface.

Tags: multi-tenant

How can I make the ITenantConfiguration SessionFactory setter private and still be able to set it thrue a the Tenant class? What do I need to rebuild it to get it to work?
I want the ISessionFactory to be set inside a Tenant creation, not from outside.

```
public interface ITenantConfiguration
{
   ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; /*make private setter here*/ set; }
}

public class Tenant : ITenant
{
    public ITenantConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Tenant(ITenantConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

        //Configuration.SessionFactory = CreateConfig(); 
    }

    public ISessionFactory CreateConfig()
    {
        return Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(DatabaseConfiguration)
            .Mappings(MapAssemblies)
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    //..... removed for clarity
 }

public class TenantConfiguration : ITenantConfiguration
{
    public NHibernate.ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; /*private set;*/ set; } 
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made them internal, thats it, should have thought of that...